# Can not use Eureka Log function in module

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, eurekalog

I am getting some error while running my Delphi XE2 application with Eureka log. I have a licensed copy of Eureka Log and follow all the steps as per document, but still getting the error below:

[image: Eureka Log error while running application]

> EurekaLog 7.0.7.1 crash report
>
> Cannot use EurekaLog's functions in module (*censored*) without activated EurekaLog.
> Use IDE's "Project/EurekaLog Options..." menu item to activate EurekaLog.

This error is coming when I try to run the application. Compiler directives are correct and all the included files and components are also correct. My application was working fine 3 months ago but suddenly it stopped.

I checked the license: it is up-to-date. Checked Project/Eureka Log Options as well: everything is good.

Comment: Ask Eurekalog support.

Comment: Press Ctrl+C in such dialog windows to get all its text into the clipboard. Then paste that text here instead of pictures you even need to manipulate. Text can be searched/found, pictures. not.

Comment: At least go through the troubleshooting in the documentation and tell us the results. https://www.eurekalog.com/help/eurekalog/index.php?enabling_eurekalog_problems.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elephant in the room:

> I checked license it is up-to-date

Your screenshot says EurekaLog version is 7.0.7.1. It was released 10 years ago!

1. If you have a modern license - why you are not using the latest/modern version of EurekaLog (7.11.*x*)?
2. If you **are** using the latest/modern version of EurekaLog - then this message comes not from your application, but perhaps from some other module (DLL), which was compiled with old EurekaLog version.

Now, back to the question.

The message is displayed when your application does not have embedded EurekaLog's options and debug information. This means that the application was not [post-processed](https://www.eurekalog.com/help/eurekalog/eurekalog_basics.php) to inject required information.

You can double-confirm this by using the `Start / Programs / EurekaLog / Tools / PE Analyzer` tool for your compiled executable. I highly suspect that it will show you that your application does not have EurekaLog's data on board.

Now, once you have confirmed that your application was not compiled with EurekaLog - you have to find the reason why that is.

The usual way would be to look at the compiler's output (`View / Tool Windows / Messages`, usually located at the bottom of the IDE). There should be output from EurekaLog there. See if it runs or chokes. If it fails - there should be a reason indicated.

[This article](https://www.eurekalog.com/help/eurekalog/enabling_eurekalog_problems.php) contains a troubleshooting guide with step by step instructions. You said

> follows all the steps as per document

Did you see / follow that article? It contains screenshots of every step and every correct output.

If you still fail to resolve your issue - please, post screenshots and outputs from each step described in your article, specifically - answer the following questions:

1. Do you see EurekaLog's menu items in IDE?
2. Is your project configured via `Project / EurekaLog options`?
3. Does your project have map file set to `Detailed`?
4. Does your project have `EUREKALOG` conditional symbol defined?
5. Do you see "EurekaLog" stage in IDE's project compilation progress dialog?
6. Do you see output from EurekaLog in IDE's build log (check both tabs)? If yes - copy/paste it here.
7. Wipe all old `*.dcu` files and reinstall EurekaLog. Sometimes it is possible that your IDE will use a mix of old and new EurekaLog's files. For example, if you run your IDE in compatibility mode, some files may go into Windows `VirtualStore` and override the actual / modern files from `Program Files` folder.
8. If everything else fails - check if you are actually looking at the correct executable.

P.S. There is also a [very similar error with similar resolution steps](https://support.eurekalog.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/48/9/7x-unexpected-the-program-is-compiled-with-eurekalog-7-trial-version).